# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django

In my Django project, I want to make a simple booking system, that works by clicking a button on the main page that redirects you to view named book_cd. In URL we have cd_name (id) that is converted into var named name in mine view. Problem is that I can't use filter() function to find that one record I want to update because something like this happens:

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

in line with:

```
results = CD.objects.filter(CD.info.name == name)
```

my models:

```
class CD(models.Model):
    pass


class CDInfo(models.Model):
    cd = models.OneToOneField(CD, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='info')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class CDBooking(models.Model):
    cd = models.OneToOneField(CD, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='booking')
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    when_booked = models.DateTimeField(timezone.now())
```

my view:

```
def book_cd(request, CD, cd_name):
name = cd_name

results = CD.objects.filter(CD.info.name == name)

for CD in results:
    CD.booking.user = "test"
    CD.save()

return redirect('index')
```

I tried with and without request and CD in function arguments, no idea what to do.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

full views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import CD
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from HORSeWebSite.forms import SignUpForm


def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template("HORSeWebSite/index.html")
    list_of_cds = CD.objects.all()
    context = {
        'CDs': list_of_cds

    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})


def book_cd(CD, cd_name):
    name = cd_name

    results = CD.objects.filter(CD.info.name == name)

    for CD in results:
        CD.booking.user = "a"
        CD.save()

    return redirect('index')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "HORSeWebSite"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('book/<int:cd_name>', views.book_cd, name='cd_name'),
]
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/HORSeWebSite/book/013

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'HORSeWebSite.apps.HorsewebsiteConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\eraepkj\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\eraepkj\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\eraepkj\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /HORSeWebSite/book/013
Exception Value: book_cd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'CD'
```

Comment: You have swapped arguments when calling this function I think. But actually your code has a lot of errors,  especially with filter method.  Please follow the docs to get some understanding of Django orm

Comment: Rename the CD parameter as it may be shadowing the model import. I would also recommend changing the for loop to remove any ambiguity around the CD variable. e.g for result in results.

Comment: Please show the full view, the urls.py and the complete traceback. The code you've shown wouldn't give that error; but as Alexandr says there are lots of other errors in this code as well.

Comment: added full views, urls and traceback to the main post, btw whenever I change arguments in this function there's always something missing, mainly objects and CD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your view code as below

```
def book_cd(request, cd_name):
  name = cd_name
  results = CD.objects.filter(info__name=cd_name)
  for cd in results:
    cd.booking.user = "a"
    cd.save()
  return redirect('index')
```

for every function based view first argument must be a `request` followed by other arguments.

Comment: local variable 'CD' referenced before assignment, anyway thanks for explanation about `request`

Comment: `local variable 'CD' referenced before assignment`, also CD is underlined all the time

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: booking, id, info`

Comment: what do you mean by update? if u ask me to show You my models, I did that in the main post

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'cdinfo' into field. Choices are: booking, id, info`